# Error message on pivot table generation using Apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have been trying to create a pivot table from some data on my excel table using apache poi 3.17 and poi-ooxml 3.17.
But while opening the generated excel file, there is a popup with some error message that the

For the timebeing I am passing the same sheet reference to sheet and Tablesheet variable. The sheet contains a table with some data to be pivoted. What could be the cause of this error message and how am I likely to fix this?

I would appreciate any help from the community.

```
 private void writePivotTableToWrkBck(final XSSFSheet sheet, final XSSFSheet Tablesheet, final CellAttribute cellAttribute) {

//      System.out.println("Started creating pivotTable");
//      int firstRow = Tablesheet.getFirstRowNum();
//      int lastRow = Tablesheet.getLastRowNum();
//      int firstCol = Tablesheet.getRow(0).getFirstCellNum();
//      int lastCol = Tablesheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
//      
//      
//      CellReference topLeft = new CellReference(1, 1);
//      CellReference botRight = new CellReference(6, 4 - 1);
//      
//      AreaReference aref = new AreaReference(topLeft, botRight, SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007);
//      CellReference pos = new CellReference(firstRow + 8, lastCol + 1);
//      
//      XSSFPivotTable pivotTable =sheet.createPivotTable(aref, pos);
//      pivotTable.addRowLabel(0);
//      pivotTable.addRowLabel(1);
//      pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM,
//                    4, "Sum of " );

         AreaReference source = new AreaReference("A1:D4", SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007);
         CellReference position = new CellReference("H5");
         // Create a pivot table on this sheet, with H5 as the top-left cell..
         // The pivot table's data source is on the same sheet in A1:D4
         XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = sheet.createPivotTable(source, position);
         //Configure the pivot table
         //Use first column as row label
         pivotTable.addRowLabel(0);
         //Sum up the second column
         pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 1);
         //Set the third column as filter
         pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.AVERAGE, 2);
         //Add filter on forth column
         pivotTable.addReportFilter(3);

        System.out.println("End creating pivotTable");

    }
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Your screen-shot of the Excel sheet lacks the column and row headers, why? But if first showed cell is `A1`, then maybe the table range, which is up to column `I` then,  overlaps the pivot table range, which starts at `H5`?

Comment: I was able to resolve it finally. The problem came from the libraries which were not compatible with each other. swapping them with the right one did wonders ;)

Comment: Even with empty rows and columns I should have been able to generate an empty pivot table.